# AND Operation on 2 columns (access and mofidy dates) in a file in linux

Tags: sed, awk

I have a large millions of records file which consists of "directories, file names , permission, group and owner, size, last accessed date, last modified date, last changed date ). I need to get the rows (files) that have last accessed date AND the last modified date less than or equal to 2012.

Example:

```
23 8 drwx------ 16 userid grpid 2048 2009-06-25 20:42 2011-03-03 17:27 2011-03-03 17:27 /path/dir
66738 8 drwx--S--- 3 userid grpid 1024 2010-03-05 11:49 2015-07-07 17:48 2010-03-05 11:49 /path/dir/dir2
90354 8 -rw-r----- 1 userid grpid 65536 2016-05-25 15:28 2008-05-22 12:00 2014-03-05 16:00 /path/dir/dir2/file1
89743 8 -rw-r----- 1 userid grpid 65536 2016-05-25 15:28 2008-05-22 12:00 2010-03-05 16:00 /path/dir/dir2/file2
```

Comment: give it a little more thought: which columns are you interested in comparing? do you know what the awk "logical and" operator is? do you know how to compare two strings?

Comment: Thanks for your quickest response. I would like to compare column 8 and 10 and if both are having year 2012 or prior, then i need those lines listed into a new file. if any one of them is greater than 2012, then i don't need it. I'm not aware of "logical and" operator as i'm not familiar with awk that much.

Comment: To help any readers that come in the future, you should add your answer below.

Comment: Why would ever want a logical AND between a condition on accessed and modified date? An entry will **fail** your test if it has been modified more recently than 2012 or if it has been accessed more recently. What's the use? If a file is modified, it is usually accessed: you're not going to have a file modified in 2016 that was last accessed in 2012.  Or, rather, if you do, it's only because the filesystem is mounted such that access times are not being updated (e.g "noatime" mount option on Linux). In which case, access times are a fairly useless thing to evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest awk code would be:

```
awk '$3 ~ /^-/ && $8 < "2013" && $10 < "2013"' file
```

This uses the default action (print) for records that pass the test.
It also takes advantage of lexical sorting where:

- `"2012-12-31" < "2013"` is true and
- `"2013-01-01" < "2013"` is false

Answer (score 0):

Sample input modified to get one matching line in output

```
$ cat ip.txt 
23 8 drwx------ 16 userid grpid 2048 2009-06-25 20:42 2011-03-03 17:27 2011-03-03 17:27 /path/dir
66738 8 -rwx--S--- 3 userid grpid 1024 2010-03-05 11:49 2011-07-07 17:48 2010-03-05 11:49 /path/dir/dir2
90354 8 -rw-r----- 1 userid grpid 65536 2016-05-25 15:28 2008-05-22 12:00 2014-03-05 16:00 /path/dir/dir2/file1
89743 8 -rw-r----- 1 userid grpid 65536 2016-05-25 15:28 2008-05-22 12:00 2010-03-05 16:00 /path/dir/dir2/file2

$ grep -P '^(\S+\s+){2}-(?1){5}(\d\d(0\d|1[0-2]))(?1){2}(?2)' ip.txt 
66738 8 -rwx--S--- 3 userid grpid 1024 2010-03-05 11:49 2011-07-07 17:48 2010-03-05 11:49 /path/dir/dir2
```

- `(\S+\s+)` non-space text followed by white-space. `{5}` or `{2}` tells it to be repeated that many times
- `\d\d(0\d|1[0-2])` for years `2012` or prior (assuming first two digits in year doesn't exceed `20`)
- `(?1)` refers to `(\S+\s+)` and `(?2)` refers to `(\d\d(0\d|1[0-2]))`

`perl` solution similar to [glenn's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/311156/109046)

```
$ perl -ae 'print if $F[2] =~ /^-/ && $F[7] < 2013 && $F[9] < 2013' ip.txt 
66738 8 -rwx--S--- 3 userid grpid 1024 2010-03-05 11:49 2011-07-07 17:48 2010-03-05 11:49 /path/dir/dir2
```

Add `> output.txt` to end of command to save the results to another file

Answer (score -1):

AWK And Operator helped me here.. As I needed only files and not directories, I filtered the file for permissions column starting with "-".

cat filename | awk '($3 ~ /^-/ )'

Then cut down the date format to represent year as I'm only concerned on it using sed .

cat filename | awk '($3 ~ /^-/ )' | sed 's/-[0-9][0-9]//g'

Now awk AND operator compared two columns and I got the output what I'm expecting.

cat filename | awk '($3 ~ /^-/ )' | sed 's/-[0-9][0-9]//g' | awk ' $8 < 2013 && $10 < 2013 ' > files_older_2012

Thanks for everyone. This is the best place I ever visited.